# jquery get img size and change its css properties based on width/height proportions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, width

I have a dynamic image loading in a fixed width and height div. What i would like my javascript to do is

1) understand the image width and height
2) calculate its proportion and..
3) if its width is > height then give it height:100%, else give it width 100% instead.

here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/vWGMf/2/

this code can't grab the proportions of the images and well.. it just doesn't work.. the messy js part is the following:

```
var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {

var containerWidth  = $(".container").width();

var containerHeight = $(".container").height();

var imgWidth   = $(".image").width();
var imgHeight  = $(".image").height();


if(imgWidth > imgHeight) {
            $(".image").css({"width": "auto","height": "100%", "top": 0});

        }
        else {
            $(".image").css({"width": "100%", "height": "auto", "left": 0});

        }
}
```

can anybody help??? thank you so much!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

so your var 'newImg' doesn't know what image needs to be loaded. You need to add after new Image()...

```
newImg.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
```

here is a jsfiddle showing this

http://jsfiddle.net/vWGMf/4/

good luck!

Comment: I think this should have solved the height > width || width > height problem :)